# I keep getting a error while running this jsp page

Tags: javascript, java

Everytime I run my jsp file, I get the following error,
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

root cause 
java.lang.NullPointerException
here is my jsp code, ask if you need any other code, i'll edit the question to do so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
      </style>
   </head>

       <% 
           Account a1 = (Account)session.getAttribute("a1");
           %>
      <h1 align="center"> SUMMARY</h1>
      <br>
      </br>
      <form action="AccountLookupServlet" method="Post">
         <div>
            <label for="AcctNo">Accnt ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name ="AcctNo" value="<%=a1.getAcctNo()%>"/></br>
            <label for="CustID">Cust ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="CustID " value="<%=a1.getCid()%>"/></br>
            <label for="Type">Type: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Type" value="<%=a1.getType()%>"/></br>
            <label for="Balance">Balance:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Balance" value="<%=a1.getBalance()%>"/></br>

         </div>
         <div>
         <input type="submit" name="subBtn" value="lookup"/>

         <input type="reset" name="rstBtn" value="clear"/>
      </form>
```

Comment: Can you share your stacktrace with the error included?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not put "a1" to your session. Or you have put, but was `null`.

1) Show us the code where you put "a1" to the session.

2) Tell us what you do before you call this JSP. If you didn't put "a1" to the session and directly called this JSP, than of course you will get this exception.

Comment: HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            Account a1 = (Account)session.getAttribute("a1"); i put those after defining each of the string in the lookup servlet

Comment: These lines **don't show** that you put "a1" to the session. Check you code, it seems you forgot to put "a1" to the session. If you put it, check *when* do you do that. "a1" should be put to the session *before* this JSP is called.